# How to insert data into multiple table in laravel from single Controller?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

[I am new in Laravel]

I am using Laravel 5.5

I have **ProductController** and model **Product** also I have two tables **products** and **pcategories**. I want to insert data into **pcategories** table from **ProductController**. How to do this properly? I have used `DB::table('pcategories')->`enter code here`insert($data);` but it's not inserting `created_at` and `updated_at` value.

Another question: Can I call multiple models into a controller?

This is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use Image;

class ProductController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        $product->categorieslist = Product::table('pcategories')->get();
        return view('product.add')->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        $product->categorieslist = Product::table('pcategories')->get();
        return view('product.add')->with($data);
    }

    public function all() {
        $product->products = Product::table('products')->get();
        return view('product.all', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'producttitle' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);

        $product = new Product;

        $image = $request->file('photo');
        if ($request->file('photo')) {
            $product->photo = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imagePath = public_path('/images/product');
            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(250, 250, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($imagePath . '/' . $product->photo);
        }

        $product->title = $request->input('producttitle');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->category = $request->input('category');
        $product->price = $request->input('price');
        $product->saleprice = $request->input('saleprice');
        $product->weight = $request->input('weight');
        $product->dimension = $request->input('dimension');
        $product->color = $request->input('color');
        $product->save();
        return redirect('/product/')->with('success', 'Successfully Added');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        return view('product.show')->with('product', $product);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        $data['product'] = Product::find($id);        
        $data['categorieslist'] = Product::table('pcategories')->get();
        return view('product.edit')->with($data);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'producttitle' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);

        $product = Product::find($id);

        $image = $request->file('photo');
        if ($request->file('photo')) {
            $product->photo = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imagePath = public_path('/images/product');
            $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(250, 250, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            })->save($imagePath . '/' . $product->photo);
        }

        $product->title = $request->input('producttitle');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->category = $request->input('category');
        $product->price = $request->input('price');
        $product->saleprice = $request->input('saleprice');
        $product->weight = $request->input('weight');
        $product->dimension = $request->input('dimension');
        $product->color = $request->input('color');
        $product->save();
        return redirect('/product/all')->with('success', 'Successfully Updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        Product::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect('/product/all')->with('success', 'Successfully Deleted');
    }

    public function category() {
        $data['categories'] = DB::table('pcategories')->get();
        return view('product.category')->with($data);
    }

    public function storecategory(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'category' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data = array();
        $data['category'] = $request->input('category');
        DB::table('pcategories')->insert($data);
        return redirect('/product/category')->with('success', 'Successfully Added');
    }

    public function categorydestroy($id) {
        DB::table('pcategories')->where('id', $id)->delete();
        return redirect('product/category/')->with('success', 'Successfully Deleted');
    }

}
```

Comment: can u show me your controller code??

Comment: public function storecategory(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'category' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $data = array();
        $data['category'] = $request->input('category');
        DB::table('pcategories')->insert($data);
        return redirect('/product/category')->with('success', 'Successfully Added');
    }

Comment: Your question is unclear. Also, what have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Hi this is my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Eloquent Model` instead of `Query Builder`. Fields `created_at`,`updated_at` are "part" of `Eloquent`. You either use `Eloquent` or insert `manually` those fields.

If you want to use `Eloquent`, then make two model `Product` and `PCategory`. And then insert with your model.

```
PCategory::create($data);
```

And you need to `mass assigned` your field on model class.If you don't want to mass assigned your fields, than do like this-

```
$pcategory = new PCategory();
//$pcategory->column1 = $data['column1'] or $data->column1;
$pcategory->save();
```

To learn more, follow [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) official doc.

And for your second part, **Yes**, You can.

Comment: glad it helps you :)

Comment: do you have a updated link to the documentation of PCategory?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor look at this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models

Answer (score 0):

First, create a proper relationship with your models ( one to many, etc. )
Second, you can use the DB::transact to insert data into multiple tables in DB. It has it's own advantages rather than just inserting Fk in tables to fill in the data. For further info you can search in google.